# Can't loop throw cards that take there information from a mongoose DB using jquery

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

I got the following code

```
      <% topic.forEach(function(topic){ %>
          <div class="col-4">
              <div id="homecard" class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                  <a href="/home/<%= topic._id %>"><img class="card-img-top" src="<%= topic.image %>" alt="Card image cap"></a>
                  <div class="card-body">
                      <span id="homecategory" class="card-title"><%= topic.category %></span>
                      <p id="homesubject" class="card-text text-center mt-3"><%= topic.subject %></p>
                  </div>
              </div> 
          </div>
      <% }); %>

<script>
    var card = $("#homecard");
    card.forEach(function(card){
        $(this).click(function(){
        console.log("done");
        });
    })
</script>
```

The ejs code print the information which has been taking from a mongoos database by using express ever one in a different card.

I want to loop throw all the card and do something using Jquery but i cant because it only recognize the first card.

If anyone can help and find a way to loop throw all of them.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what are you trying to do, but with the foreach loop you create many `div` elements with the same id `homecard`. That is a problem, ids should be unique

Comment: ID's must be unique in a page, that's why you only find the first one. Use `$('.card').click(function...` instead. No need to use `forEach`